# how to search user entered value in a list?

Tags: python, list, search, text-files

(s213,bill,72,59,45)
(s214,john,88,70,80)
(s215,anne,52,61,44)
(s216,sliva,44,50,35)
above values in the brackets are the marks.txt
and using below code it can convert in to a list

```
file=open('marks.txt','r')
marks=file.readlines()
for a in marks:
    x=a.split(',')
    print(x)
```

I want to user to enter wished student number(s213) and display the student name and the average

Comment: Please format correct and post your coding attempt; this is not valid Python syntax.

Comment: That is not a list.  Lists have brackets and the strings are quoted.  Additionally, a list is the wrong data structure for your problem. You want a dictionary. Or maybe two dictionaries.

Comment: Please refer to [help] on asking homework questions. Specifically, please show what you have tried so far

Comment: You forgot to include your attempt to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a nested `dictionary`. Here, each `key` is a student number and each `value` is another dictionary that stores the student's `name` and `scores`.

Code:

```
students = {"s213": {"name": "bill", "scores": [72, 59, 45]}, 
            "s214": {"name": "john", "scores": [88 , 70, 80]},
            "s216": {"name": "sliva", "scores": [44, 50, 35]}}
            
student_number = input("Please enter the student number: ")
print("Name: " + students[student_number]["name"])
grades = students[student_number]["scores"]
print("Average grade: " + str(sum(grades) / len(grades)))
```

Output:

```
Please enter the student number: 
s214
Name: john
Average grade: 79.33333333333333
```

Comment: String concatenation is not needed.  Try this instead: `print("Average grade:", sum(grades) / len(grades))`. The `print` function accepts (n) arguments which are to be printed.

Comment: I am aware -- there are many ways to format print statements.

For example:
`print(f"Average grade: {sum(grades) / len(grades)}")`

Answer (score 0):

use pandas for loading a csv (what im assuming the format for your data is) and for adding an 'average' column for easier getting

tmp.csv:

```
student_id,name,grade1,grade2,grade3
s213,bill,72,59,45
s214,john,88,70,80
s215,anne,52,61,44
s216,sliva,44,50,35
```

code

```py
import pandas as pd
# load csv
df = pd.read_csv('tmp.csv')
df['average'] = df.mean(axis=1)
print(df)

search_name = input('enter student name to get an average for: ')
print(df['average'][df['name'] == search_name])
```

df printed:

```
  student_id   name  grade1  grade2  grade3    average
0       s213   bill      72        59      45  58.666667
1       s214   john      88        70      80  79.333333
2       s215   anne      52        61      44  52.333333
3       s216  sliva      44        50      35  43.000000
```

result from search

```
enter student name to get an average for: bill
0    58.666667
Name: average, dtype: float64
```

NOTE: the mean method call used to get averages will try to average ALL elements of the row. string's can't be averaged so they're ignored and instead all numbers are averaged. if your data has numbers included that shouldn't be averaged, the logic will need to change